# array formula: sum to date

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a number of invoices:

| invoice # | start | end | paid on | amount | paid to date (hardcoded) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 30/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | £10.00 | £10.10 |
| 2 | 01/02/2020 | 20/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 | £7.50 | £17.60 |
| 3 | 21/02/2020 | 30/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 | £2.50 | £20.10 |
| 4 | 01/01/2000 | 30/01/2000 | 01/03/2000 | £0.10 | £0.10 |

Where the invoices

- are not necessarily sorted by start and end date
- are not necessarily sorted by paid date.
- might not have a paid-on value.

I want to add a field called `paid to date` that would show me the amount I have been paid so far where it would add the amount for:

- the current invoice
- the invoices that were paid prior to this invoice's paid-on date.
- the invoices with the same `paid-on` date as this invoice but with a start date `<=` this invoice's start date.

Effectively mirroring the hard-coded column.

This is how I do it with a query (which might not be the simplest/most elegant way of doing it)

```
=Index(
    query(
      A1:E10, 
      "select SUM(E)
      where D is not null
      and (
        D < date '"& TEXT( D2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
        OR (
          D = date '"& TEXT( D2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
          and
          B <= date '"& TEXT( B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
        )
      )"
    ),
    2, 1
  )
```

which is all well and good. but I want to be able to do it with array-formula, so I can have it auto-generated for me.

I tried using it inside array-formula but the value is only ever generated for the first row. I guess it's misinterpreting the range I am passing as the range of the query function, ie `A1:E10`. is there an easy way of fixing it?

Do I need to use VLookup?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RwLdwhjGmYiSX615meG_j66Ys5MFx1j8WgSsy6610mg/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: The answer given by [@player0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70408111/14271633) does not work for you?  I have tested it and it seems to be working, in any case, you can always use a [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#getting_a_custom_function_from_the) to have more control over it. Would this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {INDEX(SORT({A2:B, D2:E}, 2, 1, 3, 1),,1), 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(E2:E)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(E2:E)))*
 INDEX(SORT({A2:B, D2:E}, 2, 1, 3, 1),,4)), SIGN(E2:E))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: wow nice! do you mind explaining in a line or two what the strategy is?

Comment: also what is the significance of `2,1,3,1` etc?

Comment: in my actual data, i have additional columns and i need to know how to change the above to make it work.

Comment: @Mathsnoob strategy is to sort data based on dates -> given the range of columns {A,B, D,E} we sort 2nd column by 1 (ascending) and 3rd column by 1 (ascending) hance: 2,1,3,1 then we perform running total (cumulative sum) on array and pair it with sorted A column. next we perform vlookup on A column and return the correct value for correct row

Comment: ah got you! thanks. unfortunately when I try this on my actual table, it doesn't work. I am getting "Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 17379. Actual: 1."

Comment: some notes: I changed {A2:B, D2:E} to `{A2:A, B2:B, D2:D, E2:E}` as in general the columns are not next to each other. (tho still not working)

Comment: in my actual table, i dont have a id table, I replaced its use in your formula with what I do have which is `invoiced on` field. I think it should play a similar role. but it doesn't. :/ i have added the field to the sample file. (i dont understand the role of the id field in your solution tbh)

Comment: also in the actual data, some invoices have `paid-on` as empty. the above seems to ignore it in the sample case even. ideally we want the value to be empty in the sum so far whenever an invoice isnt paid yet.

Comment: as for the error I am getting, my columns are not in the order that we have in the sample file. this is what my data and query looks like. any idea why it's taking issue with it?  https://pastebin.com/NS2xQuV1 i guess I'd see it more clearly if I could see what you are trying to achieve with SIGN and TRANSPOSE :/

Comment: @Mathsnoob see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FiKvI24smQ3GcZtF25ZhH8423zjAIZSJyAOq4d1J9rY/edit#gid=0

Comment: thanks for that. I can see you have an empty row in your data which lacks both amount as well as everything else. The use case in mind has everything except the `paid-on` date. if I fill in the row except that field, your new formula still assumes it was paid and considers it in its sum. see https://ibb.co/BfxWTK7

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can Filter directly.
*Note that I am using a table with structured references. Then you don't need to adjust the range references as you add/remove rows from the table.*

```
=SUM(FILTER([amount],([paid on]<[@[paid on]])+(([paid on]=[@[paid on]])*([start]<[@start])),0),[@amount])
```

This part does the filtering:

```
...([paid on]<[@[paid on]])+(([paid on]=[@[paid on]])*([start]<[@start]))...
```

[image]

***Note:** You can use the same algorithm in Sheets:*
*Note that I am using regular addressing, and also using a semicolon instead of a comma for the argument separators*

```
=sum(iferror(FILTER($E$2:$E$5;($D$2:$D$5<$D2)+(($D$2:$D$5=$D2)*($B$2:$B$5<$B2)));0);E2)
```

Comment: ah looks cool! unfortunately I am primarily interested in a solution I can try on google sheets.

Comment: @Mathsnoob Perhaps you should consider removing the `Excel` tag then.

Comment: Allow me to correct myself: Excel and Google sheet has a set of common features. I am interested in a solution that utilities those. I have not tagged this question with Excel-365 for instance.

Comment: @Mathsnoob See a variation that works in both Excel and Sheets with the FILTER function.

Comment: That looks promising! thanks Ron. two observations: I can't seem to be able to use it in an array formula. as in it only generates one entry instead of generating the whole list. I tried modifying $ references to no avail: `={"Sum to date";ARRAYFORMULA(sum(iferror(FILTER(E3:E7,(D3:D7<D3:D)+((D3:D7=D3:D)*(B3:B7<B3:B))),0),E3:E))}` any idea how I can modify it to make it work? also, I want the result to not be populated if the invoice is not paid (if the paid-on field is blank) as suggested in the question. Your formula doesnt seem to be doing that atm.

Comment: @Mathsnoob 1. The formula will only output a single result.  In Excel, with Tables, it would auto-populate the entire column with the formula entered in the first cell.  You will have to figure out if that is doable in Sheets, else you'll have to copy the formula down. 2. It was not clear to me, nor was there an example in your sample data of an unpaid invoice. If you wind up using my formula, just wrap it in an `IF` to check if paid-on field is blank, and return either the result of the formula if not blank, or something else if it is blank.